# Xcode 7.2 DTCoreText 'CTLineUtils.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, dtcoretext

I have installed DTCoreText within CocoaPods, but this message always appear when trying to build:

```
'CTLineUtils.h' file not found
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

deleted pods folder and Podfile.lock and did a `pod install` ...
now it's working.